# Put two Highcharts Charts Side by Side on a Jekyll Blog (beautiful-jekyll)

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, jekyll

I am currently working with highcharts in Jekyll and have seen documentation on how to put two 'divs'
together, but I was unsure on how I could do this in Jekyll using CSS. My current jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0u2r1ztj/20/) where the two charts are stacked.

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<div id="container2" style="height: 400px"></div>

<script>
  const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    //plot options code with type: 'datetime'
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 2, 4),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
      }
    },
    type: 'line',
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      split: false,
      enabled: true,
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],

      },



      {
        data: [5, 15, 20, 10, 1],

      }
    ]
  });
</script>

<script>
  const chart2 = Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    //plot options code with type: 'datetime'
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 2, 4),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
      }
    },
    type: 'line',
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      split: false,
      enabled: true,
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [5, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.9],

      },



      {
        data: [13, 15, 20, 30, 11],

      }
    ]
  });
</script>
```

I have seen documentation on how to do this but was unsure on how to implement this in [beautiful-jekyll, a custom jekyll theme.](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll) I tried to edit/modify the heading titles for my jekyll website but was unsuccessful and therefore, was unsure on how to do this with css.

Was looking for any suggestions on how to do this by either modifying my source HTML file or my Jekyll CSS file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed the following application by adding the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) library to the project. On a large enough screen, two graphs will appear side by side. Graphics will appear one after the other when the page gets too small due to responsive design rules. Click [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/sercansebetci/16othg47/#) to test the application.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Remove the styles applied to the following <div> element to position the container at (0,0) in the application. -->
  <div class="row" style="padding: 50px; margin-top: 25px;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="container" style="height: 500px"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="container2" style="height: 500px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
      //plot options code with type: 'datetime'
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 2, 4),
          pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
        }
      },
      type: 'line',
      tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        split: false,
        enabled: true,
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
      },

      series: [{
          data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        },
        {
          data: [5, 15, 20, 10, 1],
        }
      ]
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    const chart2 = Highcharts.chart('container2', {
      //plot options code with type: 'datetime'
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 2, 4),
          pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
        }
      },
      type: 'line',
      tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        split: false,
        enabled: true,
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
      },
      series: [{
          data: [5, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.9],
        },
        {
          data: [13, 15, 20, 30, 11],
        }
      ]
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```